# Is it possible for me to expand the grid of the main content area?

Tags: laravel, grid, sidebar, collapsable

I'm trying to make my dashboard app more dynamic by adding a collapsable navbar. The nav should resize to only icons, and the main area should expand. But I'm kind of stuck on how to expand it from now on.

The project is based on the PHP Laravel framework 5.6.

I have tried different setups with grid columns.

```php
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        @include("test.components.sidenav")
        <main class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-10 pt-3 pl-4 ml-auto">
            <div class="container-fluid" id="expandable">
                <nav class="sidebar col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2" id="collapseId">
                    <h1 class="site-title">
                        <a href="{{ route('home') }}">
                            <em class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></em>
                            <span>Ready4It</span>
                        </a>
                    </h1>
                    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">
                        <em class="fas fa-bars"></em>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column sidebar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="">
                                <em class="fas fa-home"></em>
                                <span>Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="">
                                <em class="fas fas fa-ticket-alt nav-bar-icon"></em>
                                <span>Ticket overzicht</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="">
                                <em class="fas fa-chart-line"></em>
                                <span>Statistieken</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="">
                                <em class="fas fa-envelope"></em>
                                <span>Mail monitoring</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="">
                                <em class="fas fa-clock"></em>
                                <span>Uren invoer</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <a href="#" class="logout-button" id="logout-button">
                        <em class="fa fa-power-off"></em>
                        <span>Logout</span>
                    </a>
                </nav>
                <section class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            @yield("content")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    /* This script is for the mobile navbar collapse */
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });

    $("#menu-collapse").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#collapseId").toggleClass("icons-only");
        $("#logout-button").toggleClass("logout-button").toggleClass("logout-button-collapsed")
    })
</script>
```

The nav should resize to only icons, and the main area should expand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,
Add a fixed width to the class icons-only also adjust transform translate if needed

```
.icons-only {
 width: some-width;
}
```

and also make sure you added same width as margin-left for main section ( apply this only if the icons-only class is added to nav )